Can I provide solution to ampl and check which constraints were violated?
I'm trying to fix my model for which I have a solution that should work. Is it possible to provide that solution to the solver and see which and how constraints are violated?
Edit:
Let's say I have objective function:
maximize objective_function:
    sum {i in S1, j in S2, k in S3} x[i,j,k] * y[i,j];

I have xs that should be a feasible solution. I want to plug them in to see what happens to constraints and maybe find out why they are not feasible.

Some solvers have the iis option (or something like iisfind to find the "irreducible infeasible set"). For example, you could send your problem to Gurobi through option iisfind=1, or look into other solvers options, depending on your problem.
Other option is to start adding constraints "one by one", until you find the infeasibility :) You can automate this process easily through the get_constraints() function...
# read the model...
# ...

# get every constraint
cons = [c for c in ampl.get_constraints()]

# drop all the constraints so you have an "unconstrained problem"
for c_name, c in ampl.get_constraints():
  print(f"Removing {c_name}...")
  c.drop()

# restore every constraint so you notice when it becomes infeasible
for c_name, c in ampl.get_constraints():
  print(f"Adding {c_name}...")
  c.restore()
  ampl.solve()
  # print(ampl.solve_result)
  if ampl.solve_result == 'infeasible':
    print('Infeasible!!')
    break


The script is helpful indeed, but it doesn't answer my question. I want to see what values my constraints will take for a given solution, even if it's infeasible. IIS contains every single constraint, so it's not much help either.

You can see the value (or "body") of a constraint c with display c.body. That might not working depending on when your infeasibility is found.
If Ampl's presolve noticed it was infeasible, it won't send any problem to the solver so you won't find any body in there. Is that your case? Which solver are you using?
